# How many distinct functions for a set containing four elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, nonclassical-logic

How many distinct unary and binary functions can be defined on a set containing four elements?

Edit:

How many distinct unary and binary operations can be defined on a set containing four elements?

Comment: you need to specify the output domain as well, otherwise the answer is "infinitely many"

Comment: output domain is the same set.

Comment: This question isn't off-topic.  Max_b's comment indicates that he wants to know how many distinct unary and binary *operations* can get defined on a four element set.  This sort of information comes as important for abstract algebra, as well as multi-valued logic.

Comment: Max_b Every unary and binary operation can get described by a rectangular "truth table".  If you leave the middle entries blank, then you have 4 choices for each middle entry.  So, for a unary function (operation hereafter), you have 4 choices for each of the 4 entries.  By the product rule of combinatorics we then have (4*4*4*4)=256 unary operations.  For binary operations we have 16 blank entries.  So, we have (4^16)=4,294,967,296 binary operations.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Let $A$ be a $4$-element set, say $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$. Imagine defining a unary function $f:A\to A$ one value at a time: you have $4$ choices for $f(a_1)$, $4$ choice for $f(a_2)$, $4$ choices for $f(a_3)$, and $4$ choices for $f(a_4)$. You can make those choices in $4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4=4^4=256$ ways.

To define a binary function $f:A\times A\to A$, you’re still going to be making a bunch of $4$-way choices; how many such choices will you need to make, and what is the final number of binary functions on $A$?